# Tkinter button not reacting as I expected with Sleep with python

Tags: python, tkinter, sleep

I am attempting to make a log in button where the password flashes red then goes back to regular when the incorrect password is typed however it is not working.

```
#   A program creates a window on your screen using Tkinter.
import tkinter as tk
import time 
def testmybutton():
    Correctpassword = "Pa$$w0rd"
    frame_auth.tkraise()
    password = ent_password.get()
    username = ent_username.get()
    if password == Correctpassword:
        lbl_new.config(text='Logged in')
    else:
        frame_login.tkraise()
        ent_password.config(bg="red")
        time.sleep(2)
        ent_password.config(bg='white')
# main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_geometry("200x150")
root.title('Authorization')

frame_login = tk.Frame(root)
frame_login.grid(row=0, column=0, stick='NEWS')

lbl_username = tk.Label(frame_login, text='Username:', cursor="heart", bg='white', relief='flat')
lbl_username.pack()

ent_username = tk.Entry(frame_login, bd=5)
ent_username.pack(padx=40)


lbl_password = tk.Label(frame_login, text='password:', cursor="heart", bg='white', relief='flat')
lbl_password.pack()

ent_password = tk.Entry(frame_login, bd=5, show='+')
ent_password.pack(padx=40)

lbl_button = tk.Button(frame_login, text='LOG IN:', cursor="pirate", bg='white', relief='raised', command=testmybutton)
lbl_button.pack()


tk.Label(frame_login,text="Password:",font="Courier")

frame_auth = tk.Frame(root)
frame_auth.grid(row=0, column=0, stick='NEWS')

lbl_new = tk.Label(frame_auth, text='New Window:', cursor="heart", bg='white', relief='flat')
lbl_new.pack()


frame_login.tkraise()



root.mainloop()`
```

I have tried creating a second function and calling that within the test my button function however that didnt work either.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using `sleep` anywhere in a tkinter app, as it will cause the main UI thread / event loop to hang while sleeping.

Instead, you should use the builtin `tkinter.after()` method, which allows you to call a function after a given number of milliseconds

```
def testmybutton():
    Correctpassword = "Pa$$w0rd"
    frame_auth.tkraise()
    password = ent_password.get()
    username = ent_username.get()
    if password == Correctpassword:
        lbl_new.config(text='Logged in')
    else:
        frame_login.tkraise()
        ent_password.config(bg="red")
        # call this function anonymously after 2000mS (2 seconds)
        root.after(2000, lambda: ent_password.config(bg='white'))
```

I'm using `root.after()` here since `root` is your instance of `Tk`

Comment: Hi thank you for your knowledge! However i am still getting an error, when i tried that its telling me "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__name__'"

Comment: Does your editor tell you what line is causing that error? I don't see any calls to `.name` in the code you posted

Comment: The error code im getting says     return self.tk.call('after', ms, name)
_tkinter.TclError: bad argument "<function testmybutton.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x0000022CCA4BD120>": must be cancel, idle, info, or an integer

Comment: it wont let me type all of it because of the word limit but that is the part i think that matters. I think its referring to the call in tkinter, however im not very sure. I didnt change anything in my code besides the two lines you changed.

Comment: Ah, sorry, that's my mistake. I had the arguments for the call to `after` in the wrong order. It should be `ms` followed by `func` (I had it backwards). I've updated the answer to fix this!